# Java сравнение массивов через вычитание

Tags: java, android, массивы

У меня есть четыре массива. `r1`:

```
String[] r1={item1,item2,item3,item4,item5};
```

массив `check`:

```
String[] check={text1.getText().toString(),text2.getText().toString(),text3.getText().toString(),text4.getText().toString(),text5.getText().toString(), ... , text10.getText().toString()};
```

то есть, заведомо неизвестно содержимое массива check.
Есть также два массива, где я просто фиксирую результаты `rezmax[]` и `similar[]`.

Понять нужно, содержится ли в массиве `check` хотя бы 4 из 5 элементов массива `r1`. Вот такой код я придумал, но походу неправильно вычитаю:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
int counter = 0;
Arrays.asList(r1).removeAll(Arrays.asList(check)); // здесь я вычитаю один массив из другого, и, кажется, тут что-то не так
for (String s : r1) if (!s.isEmpty()) list.add(s); // здесь я удаляю пустые элементы, которые должны стать пустыми после вычитания
r1=list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
for (int i = 0; i < r1.length; i++) // здесь я подсчитываю количество оставшихся
{if (r1[i] != null) counter ++;}
if(counter==0){rezmax[1]=1;}else if(counter==1){similar[1]=1;} // а здесь подвожу итоги
```

А за что минусить то???

Comment: А зачем `getText().toString()`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Этот массив содержит в себе тексты из полей для ввода

Comment: Ну `text1` это, видимо, текстовое поле. `text1.getText()` уже должен возвращать строку, разве нет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, хм, ну, может быть, не пробовал, но попробую, спасибо) А по сабжу подскажите что-нибудь?

Comment: @NickVolynkin getText() возвращает [Editable](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/Editable.html), поэтому toString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой код:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> aList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(r1));

int i = 0;

for (String s : aList) {
    if (list.contains(s))
        i++;
}

if (i >= 4) {
    System.out.println("Содержатся");
}
```

Comment: гениально, спасибо!

Comment: `System.out.println(i >=4 ? "Содержатся" : "Не содержатся")`

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, многие новички не знают про тернарную условную операцию. Поэтому я подумал, что так будет проще и нагляднее.